# Is it a must to draw all actors in an activity diagram?

Tags: uml, actor, activity-diagram

I just drew an activity diagram, and I have 14 actors in my case. (I am making an activity diagram of online shopping site.)

Anyway... I am facing a problem with it, I am curious whether I must draw all actors in my diagram.

I have few system actors, so I am confusing how I place those actors between normal actors and system actors.

There are seller, non-seller who only buy products, and a manager who checks product posts. And finally I have to draw shipping system, certifying credit  system, and more.

Thank you.

Comment: How about posting your diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say your use case is cut the wrong way. If it involves 14 actors then it looks like a pot of spaghetti and you did not sort out well. Look at the use case and try to find out what is wrong. There should not be more than 3 actors involved.